# setTimeout as object in IE8 and lower

Tags: javascript, object, internet-explorer-8, settimeout

I'm sorry I have to ask for this, because there are many similar questions here, but I can't find a solution of my problem. I use setTimeout and it works in alle browsers, chrome, ff and also in IE9 and higher. But in IE8 the things that should execute after the timeout do not work. I hope someboday can help me with it...

```
var searching = {
    initialize: function (config) {
        this.wait(config.time);
    },
    wait: function(time) {
        setTimeout(function(){      
            $("#example-div").hide;
        }, time);
    }
}
$("#example-submit").click(function() {
    searching.initialize({time: 4000});
}
```

Comment: `$("#example-div").hide` doesn't look right, you need to call the function. And you're missing a closing paren.

Answer (score 0):

Reason: There is an error in your script, and other browsers continue the script execution when the error is in a setTimeout / setInterval

In case of IE this does not happen.

So either you should fix your code, or wrap your code in `try{...}catch(e){...}` blocks.

Answer (score 0):

The code is almost right. You're missing some paranthesis:

HTML:

```
<div id="example-div">example-div</div>
<div id="example-submit">example-submit</div>
```

JS:

```
var searching = {
    initialize: function (config) {
        this.wait(config.time);
    },
    wait: function(time) {
        setTimeout(function(){      
            $("#example-div").hide();
        }, time);
    }
}
$("#example-submit").click(function() {
    searching.initialize({time: 4000});
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/t6NEQ/2/